# How to insert colnames and rownames onto a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a square matrix that has 5777 columns and rows.

```
head(data)
1.3 4.5 6 7 8.9 0 7.6
4.5 6.7 8 9 0.1 8 7.2
4.5 6 7 8.9 0.1 8 8.3
6.7 8 9 0.1 7.9 6.0 5
2.4 6.7 8 3 0.1 8 7.4 
8 9 0.1 7.9 6.0 5 5.6
```

I want to insert column names and row names onto the matrix. These exist in a text file. The total number of rows this text-file has is 5777.

```
head(file.txt)

A1
B2
C3
D4
E5
F6
G7
```

How can I insert the list on the matrix (row names and column names) so it looks like this

```
A1 B2 C3 D4 E5 F6 G7
B2 1.3 4.5 6 7 8.9 0 7.6
C3 4.5 6.7 8 9 0.1 8 7.2
D4 4.5 6 7 8.9 0.1 8 8.3
E5 6.7 8 9 0.1 7.9 6.0 5
F6 2.4 6.7 8 3 0.1 8 7.4 
G7 8 9 0.1 7.9 6.0 5 5.6
```

I have tried

```
#read in row names and column names  
header <- read.table("file.txt")

#read in matrix
data <- read.table("armlympho_matrix.ld")

#set the row names and column names in matrix 
rownames(data) <- header[[1]]
colnames(data) <- header[[1]]
 
write.table(data, '/data/genome/h8/matrix_withheader.ld', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

I get no error but the output is completely wrong with no header or row inserted.

Comment: Why `row.names=FALSE`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that I particularly like.

```
data2 <- matrix(c(10, 3, 12,
                 8, 14, 7,
                 14, 17, 7, 
                 12, 7, 4 ), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

rownames(data2) <- c("Poker", "Trivial Pursuit", "Monopoly", "Wii Bowling")
colnames(data2) <- c("Pizza Rolls", "Chips and Dip", "Cookies")
```

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```r
text <- "1.3 4.5 6 7 8.9 0 7.6
4.5 6.7 8 9 0.1 8 7.2
4.5 6 7 8.9 0.1 8 8.3
6.7 8 9 0.1 7.9 6.0 5
2.4 6.7 8 3 0.1 8 7.4 
8 9 0.1 7.9 6.0 5 5.6"

test <- read.table(textConnection(text), header=FALSE, sep="")  
test <- as.matrix(test)  
colnames(test) <-  c("A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5", "F6", "G7")
```

Then you can complete yourself by `rownames(test) <- ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can set the dimnames this way:

```
m <- matrix(1:4,,2)
dimnames(m) <- list(c('A', 'B'), c('Alice', 'Bob'))
```

output:

```
## > m
  Alice Bob
A     1   3
B     2   4
```